# Confuse about jquery queue and dequeue

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, queue

I have an array, I want use jquery queue and a print function to print them out:

```
var show = function (el) { //print function 
    console.log('el', el);
}

var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var que = $({});
for (var i in arr) {
    que.queue('custom', function (next) {
        show(arr[i]);
        next();
    })
}
que.dequeue('custom');
```

but the all the print info is `e`, Why this happened?How can print is like the array order?

The second question is when I try to change the way of the `for` loop writing,like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //...
}
```

All the print info will be `undefined` . Is there difference between the two writing way? It always like the same ,doesn't it?

Here is the demo:http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/L8ExM/

Comment: Why do you need to use `queue` here? It is mostly useful for queuing animation. For simple iteration through array or object elements the fastest and easiest way is using simple `for` loop.

Comment: @VisioN The reason isn't relevant, is it? He might be trying to understand the concept.

Comment: @freakish fwiw, the concept which is not really good to apply.

Comment: @VisioN:In fact I use queue in a complicated application, which the array is stroe function, I want execute them in some order.For a short question, so I abstract it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. When your functions are called variable `i` in inner function is equal to `arr.length`, so `arr[i]` is `undefined`. You need to wrap it with an anonymous function:

```
var show = function (el) {
    console.log('el', el);
}

var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var que = $({});
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        que.queue('custom', function (next) {
            show(arr[i]);
            next();
        });
    })(i);
}
que.dequeue('custom');
```

Also, when you use `for (var i in arr)` you get `e`, because the loop stops at the last element which is `4`. The first loop stops at `5` because the condition is checked **after** incrementation.

Comment: I still don't quite understand why `the condition is checked after incrementation`, Doesn't the queue function in loop?So I think in each loop the `queue` will be executed

Comment: Yes, the code executes in a loop. And it says "attach function `F` to queue", but it **does not** call function `F` (my anonymous function **is**). When the function `F` is called (which happens when you dequeque) what is the `i` variable at that point? It is set to the last one in a loop! Because the loop finished. This happens, because blocks do not create scope. But functions do, that's why this is broken with anonymous function. You should learn more about scoping in JavaScript. This is not an easy aspect, but **very** important!